# Resize div and dynamically detect width

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, resize

This is probably a simple thing, but being a little bit of a javascript/jquery noob im botching it.

I would like to be able to have a div class, where on changing its size (either manually or as a result of dynamic size 30% etc) reports its size in pixels.

I have found various scripts some of which do similar things, but either they are not quite right .. some do window, some do document, I even found paragraph, but nothing with a div. Or I cant make sense of how its working.

Example of what I want but DIV NOT window:
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-resize-example/

Demo:
http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-resize-example.html

I suspect I need to change `$(window).resize(function () to $(div.class).resize(function ()` or something but I just cant get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out in the end: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/2uvpk2d5/

```
//DIV with .change class
$('#changelog').text(' W: ' + $('.change').width() + 'px , H:' + $('.change').height() + 'px ');

$(window).resize(function () {
$('#changelog').text(' W: ' + $('.change').width() + 'px , H:' + $('.change').height() + 'px ');
});
```

Thanks all.

Comment: This shows by window and by DIV ID and by DIV CLASS http://jsfiddle.net/n0bg26ng/20/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use window resize function . I think this will help you

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log($("yourdiv").width()); // This will report the width of your div in px.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe all you need is jquery ui resizable? since you're using jquery.

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

and it has lots of options and methods:

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: I have Jquery and the UI. What I dont know is how to target the div instead of the window or document or whatever. But thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('div#change').text("Width " + $('div#change').width() + ", height " + $('div#change').height()); 
}, 100);
```

You just simply need to use jQuery resize() method which fires when the target element is resized.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnuzyku8/5)